# Using a LINQ Query to Sort an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

I am having trouble with the LINQ query I am supposed to be using.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LinqIntegersDemo.cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] nums = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
           // var sorted = from n in nums orderby n ascending select n;
            int x = 0;

            foreach (var n in nums)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter an integer >> ");
                nums[x] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                ++x;
            }
            var sorted = from n in nums orderby n ascending select n;

            foreach (var n in nums)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked through MSDN and the snippets I have seen there told me that I wrote my query correctly. So why is it that the array is not being sorted in ascending order, which is what I need to happen.

Comment: Second foreach isn't using variable "sorted"

Comment: You want foreach (var n in sorted)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you're iterating `nums` instead of `sorted`:

```
foreach (var n in sorted)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Comment: This makes question my ability as a programmer... -.-